# Binary Search Tree key/value pair - I know the value but not the key C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, key-value

I have a simple question that I am confused about. I know what is the concept of having a key/value pair in a Binary Search Tree and how the tree looks like when it is built.

What I am unsure is of how to search for a value in such a BST if I have no track of what its key would be?

For example:

Let say I have a binary search tree full of integers (as values) and also unique integers (as keys). And let say I want to count the number of times a specific integer (lets say: 200) occurs in this BST. So what I know, 200 is the "value" and not the "key".
Hence I dont know the key at all.

How can I search now for all the "200"s in the whole BST?
Does it become a simple BST now and I dont need the key at all? But again, the tree is arranged to the left child and the right child using the "key" and not the value.

I can also give you a code sample of how I initialize the BST:

```
void insertNode(TreeNode *&p, int key, int value)
{
  if (p == NULL) {
    p = new TreeNode;
    p->key = key;
    p->value = value;
    p->left = NULL;
    p->right = NULL;
    return;
  }

  if (key < p->key)
    insertNode(p->left, key, value);
  else
    insertNode(p->right, key, value);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should state what language (computer language) you are programming in. And also the language as a tag to your question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have done the edit now.

Comment: If you are searching for the *values*, then either you swapped *key* and *value* in your implementation/concept or you don't need to store a key at all and use the value only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not take advantage of the fact that the tree is binary **search** tree if you want to search by value instead of key. So you have no other option but to iterate over the whole tree using BFS for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Thats what I was thinking but wasn't sure about it. And I am still not sure what to do. This would obviously not be something really useful of not having to use the fact of a key. This means if we are given such a tree, and are asked to search for a value rather than a key, we have no way other than standard search methods, and the concept of a Binary Search Tree dies? Bad.

Answer (score 1):

**Binary search tree(BST)** is very useful for storing data for rapid access, storage, and deletion. Data in a binary search tree are stored in tree nodes, and must have associated with them an **ordinal value** or **key**; these keys are used to structure the tree such that the value of a left child node is less than that of the parent node, and the value of a right child node is greater than that of the parent node. Sometimes, the **key** and **datum** are one and the same.

Typical key values include simple integers or strings, the actual data for the key will depend on the application. Lets consider a binary search tree that stores string/double pairs. That is, the key is the string value and the data associated with the key is a double value. Developers can search the tree using string values.

In this case, a basic recursive search algorithm will look like:

```
 node search (node, key) {
   if node is null then return null;

   if node.key = key then
      return node

   if key < node then
      return search (node.left, key);
   else
      return search (node.right, key);
  }
```

where the params are **node**: root of the tree & **key**: the value to be searched.

So typically we can search based on the required key but not on the associated value with the key.

Comment: Thanks for the response Srikanth, but again, as I stated in the question, I have no track of what the key is. I just want to count the number of times a specific value occurs in a BST without knowing any key at all.